# Pygame keystroke events not happening

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard-events

Running on pygame 1.9.4 with python3.7 windows 10,
I am not getting any KEYDOWN and KEYUP events when pressing keys.

I  have written many pygame programs and thought I understood event processing, but this has me stumped.  Adding event.pump() to the loop makes no difference.Actual keystrokes show up in the shell after terminating with ctrl-C.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
frame = 0

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            print('Keydown')
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                print('z down')
            if pygame.key.get_pressed(pygame.K_z):
                print('z pressed')

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            print('Keyup')
            if event.key == pygame.K_z:
                print('z up')

    pygame.display.flip()            
    clock.tick(1)
    frame +=1
    print(frame)
```

`

Comment: It has to be `if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_z]:`. The `break` statement breaks the event loop, rather than the main loop.

Comment: try keyboard module.

Comment: maybe problem is only `print()` and shell, not events. Did you try to draw in PyGame window when you pressed key?

Comment: `pygame.key.get_pressed(pygame.K_z)` this should give you a `TypeError: get_pressed() takes no arguments (1 given)`.

Comment: I tried that within the KETDOWN condition,, but still had no KEYDOWN event. And I really just want to know when the key is released. Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to make your player move, I guess you could include the print('z down') part

```
moving_right = False
moving_left = False

while True:
 moving_right == True:
    player_location[0] += 4
if moving_left == True:
    player_location[0] -= 4

for event in pygame.event.get(): # event loop
    if event.type == QUIT: # check for window quit
        pygame.quit() # stop pygame
        sys.exit() # stop script
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            moving_right = True
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            moving_left = True
    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_RIGHT:
            moving_right = False
        if event.key == K_LEFT:
            moving_left = False
```

Comment: You can edit your answer instead of saying the change in a comment.